# Community customization

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have a requirement where I have created an community.
Contact will create an account. This will give them access to the portal where they can login to the community at any point and can fill out an applications for the programs.
No Tabs just a home screen with user’s contact info
Link on left:
My Account
My Applications
My Groups
Chatter
Once an application is approved, user will be made a member of the corresponding group.
If part of community but not part of any programs, they will have access to general chatter
Group Pages – will have separate chatter and home page.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What you want actually?

Comment: How should I display links on home screen of community after login for account, my applications, my groups and chatter?

Comment: I would also need a functionality where a new person should be able to sign up to join the community. This will create a Contact record in the system. This community user will then look up their Account to see if it exists. The user is expected to attach their contact record to the Account. User will create a new Account if match not found.

Comment: Pay me I will make a architecture for you....

Comment: I have created link for application and account through custom link on home page .How do I create a link for chatter? I want to enable chatter in community How can I do it without using another tab for chatter?